# Как надо собирать релизную версию программы Qt, к которой подключена SQLite?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

У меня к программе подключена SQLite БД, из которой берутся таблицы журналов и автоматически генерируется форма добавления записи в журнал.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но когда я запускаю эту программу в виртуалке, где стоит только Windows, или на другом компьютере у меня не выводятся эти журналы с формами, которые берутся из БД SQLite.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что надо установить, добавить в сборку, чтоб программа брала данные из SQLite.
Подключаю я БД следующим образом:

.pro

```
...
QT += sql
...
```

login.h

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H
#include <QtSql>
#include <QMessageBox>
class Login
{
public:
    Login();
    QSqlDatabase mydb;
    void connClose()
    {
        mydb.close();
        mydb.removeDatabase(QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection);
    }


    bool connOpen()
    {
        mydb=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
        mydb.setDatabaseName(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()+"/ObservationLog.sqlite");
        qDebug()<<QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()<<QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath();
        if(!mydb.open()){
            QMessageBox msgBox;
            msgBox.setText("Не удачная попытка открыть базу");
            msgBox.exec();
            qDebug()<<("Не удачная попытка открыть базу");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug()<<("База подключена...");
            return true;
        }
    }
};

#endif // LOGIN_H
```

Comment: @Alexcei Shmakov  Да положил ObservationLog.sqlite в паку с программой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала определись с методом линковки. 
 Существует статическая и динамическая, почитай чем они отличаются и выбери одну из них. 
Если ты будешь делать статическую линковку, то тебе придется собрать qt для статической линковки, вот статейка из документации http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qtee-static-linking.html. 
Для динамической линковки все намного проще. Существует утилита *windeployqt.exe* (располагается в папке с компилятором, например *C:\QT\5.5\mingw492_32\bin\windeployqt.exe*), вызываешь ее из командой строки и в качестве аргумента к вызову этой утилиты указываешь путь до твоего .exe файла с программой и она сама соберет все нужные библиотеки и поместит их в папку с твоей программой.

Comment: там надо было положить библиотеку qsqlite.dll, которая должна лежать в корне программы папки sqldrivers. Мне это помогло, но я прочитал про методы линковки. Это надо будет сделать уже когда программа полностью будет готова. Сейчас надо только её показать.